# REST Callback with Paw

Tags: paw-app

I'm looking for help utilizing information from the header response in a REST API call.

I submit a request that returns the first 100 of 3600 records.  The header response includes a Link value that has the next URL to get the next set of records (rel="next") and a link to the last page of records (rel="last") etc.

```
Response Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
x-server-name: {removed}
Link: <https://{server.domainname.com}/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/company/companies?pageSize=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://{server.domainname.com}/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/company/companies?pageSize=100&page=35>; rel="last"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 20:56:18 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 102673
```

I can access the entire "Link" header value, but how can I get the specific values (URL's) from this item in Paw so I can use them or do I just need to do that in my code (Swift/Alamofire)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paw doesn't provide an explicit parsing of the `Link` header yet (would be nice to add though!), but you can easily work around this using the [RegExp dynamic value](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/RegexDynamicValue). In fact, you can wrap your retrieval of the `Link` header inside a RegExp search/replace pattern and extract the link you care about. Here's an example:

[image: Extract field from a header with Paw's RegExp and Header dynamic values]

I use here the regexp `.*\<([^\>]+)\>; rel="last".*` that will match the full string, and the replacement `$1` to only get the Link part we care about. I hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing! I still think it's a hacky workaround, but well…we will improve Paw and hopefully have a nicer way to do this in the next releases :)